# How to replace \n and \t with new lines and tabs respectively with one command?

Tags: regex, linux, unix, awk

I have a file name test.sh and I want to replace every `\n` and `\t` escape character with their actual newline and tab characters at the same time.

cat test.sh

```
Maria\nJimenez
Jose\tBaez
Lindo\nGarcia
Luis\tOvalle
Placido\nRuiz
```

The result output should be something like this:

```
Maria
Jimenez
Jose     Baez
Lindo
Garcia
Luis     Ovalle
Placido
Ruiz
```

I tried the following command:

```
awk '{gsub(/\\n/,"\n")}1' | awk '{gsub(/\\t/,"\t")}1' test.sh
```

But it doesn't replace both at the same time. Can I do this task with only one command?

it doesn't matter if the solution involves the use of sed, perl, tr or any other method.

Comment: When you say 'at the same time' will you accept answers that use 2 commands piped together or are you specifically asking for one command?

Comment: Either way is fine. Thanks for the replies.

Comment: Unless you use a callback, which requires a language, nothing on earth (or other worlds) will replace both at the same time. It's one first, then the other. Use 2 regex on the same file. No matter how you slice or dice it, that is what you'd end up doing with command line utilities...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`printf '%b` can interpret escape sequence so you can do just feed the file content to a `printf` command:

```
printf '%b\n' "$(<file)"

Maria
Jimenez
Jose    Baez
Lindo
Garcia
Luis    Ovalle
Placido
Ruiz
```

To save output back in file use:

```
printf '%b\n' "$(<file)" > file
```

`%b`expands all backslash escape sequences not just `\t` or `\n`. For example it will also expand `\f` (form feed) or `\r` (carriage return). Check `help printf` or `help echo` for more details.

Comment: It'd be good to give the OP a heads up that that'll do more than just interpret `\n` and `\t`.

Answer (score 2):

```
sed -i -e 's|\\n|\n|g' -e 's|\\t|\t|g' test.sh
```

Sed can execute multiple scripts in one command

```
s          # substitute
 |         # open capture block
  \\n      # match literal '\n' instead of the newline character
     |     # close capture block, open replacement block
      \n   # replace with newline character
        |  # close replacement block
         g # match multiple times per line
```

`-i` edits the file inplace

`-e` marks a script to be executed

Comment: I didn't know sed can execute multiples scripts in one command, I thought you need the pipe for that. Thanks, although, this command doesn't "do" anything.

Comment: What do you mean this doesn't do anything? This outputs the results back to the file, it doesn't print to the CLI, if you want this to output somewhere else remove the `-i` and it will output to stdout

Comment: My bad, you are right, sorry my lack of knowledge on this.

Comment: no problem :) sorry if my brief response came off a bit rude

Comment: No worries, you just taught something new about sed and I need to get better with sed and awk.

Answer (score 1):

The question's *at the same time* could be taken literally (though none of the answers did that) or interpreted as within a single process.

awk can do the latter readily enough, since it can perform more than one `gsub` in succession:

```
cat test.sh | awk '{gsub(/\\n/,"\n"); gsub(/\\t/,"\t"); print;}'
```

But (addressing the question if taken literally), **`awk`** could not do that in a single `gsub` call.  You probably could do *that* using **`perl`**, but certainly not in `sed`, etc.

Comment: Sorry, maybe the question lead to a misunderstanding, by at the same time I meant to remove both especial character under one command or script. I will change the question, although is already answered.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a conditional from the command line with PERL, like this:

```
perl -pi -w -e 's~(?:(?<NEWLINE>\\n)|(?<TAB>\\t))~$+{NEWLINE}?"\n":"\t"~egi' file_name.txt
```

All that's happening here is that it is trying to match either a `\\n` or a `\\t` and I assign them names by adding the `?<NEWLINE>` or `?<TAB>` before it.

Next, it checks to see if the named group `<NEWLINE>` has been matched with this:

```
$+{NEWLINE}?
```

And if so, then it will replace it with a newline.

```
"\n"
```

Otherwise `:`, it will replace it with a tab.

```
"\t"
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply and the effort, I didnt test it because there are other ways to get this in a easily manner.